# SQL LAST plus WHERE not giving needed result

Tags: sql

I would like to make SQL query but it is not working. Here is how my table looks like

```
Client|Product|Amount|
  A   | P1    |  5   | 
  A   | P1    |  7   | 
  A   | P1    |  3   | 
  A   | P2    |  8   | 
  A   | P2    |  0   | 
  A   | P2    |  5   | 
  A   | P3    |  9   | 
  A   | P3    |  0   |
```

I would like to set a query that would provide me a list last entries for each Client and each Product that is greater than 0. The output should look like:

```
Client|Product|Amount|
  A   | P1    |  3   |  
  A   | P2    |  5   |
```

I tried using this code

```
SELECT Client,Product, LAST(Amount) 
FROM Table 
WHERE Amount>0 
GROUP BY Client,Product
```

But I get this output:

```
Client|Product|Amount|
  A   | P1    |  3   |  
  A   | P2    |  5   | 
  A   | P3    |  9   |
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I am guessing from the use of `last()` that you are using MS Access.  You should tag the question appropriately.

Comment: Possibly want an ORDER BY http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/access-help/HV080761079.aspx *They simply return the value of a specified field in the first or last record, respectively, of the result set returned by a query. Because records are usually returned in no particular order (unless the query includes an ORDER BY clause), the records returned by these functions will be arbitrary* For this reason, the functions are pretty useless with GROUP BY (because frequently you want to order by a field that you're not grouping by - like date).

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Oracle has `last()` [as well](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions083.htm#SQLRF00653)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I'm familiar with it in the context of window functions, but I'm not familiar with it as just `last()`.  When I try that on my local version of Oracle, it insists that the function is not recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT Client, Product, LAST(Amount)
FROM Table
GROUP BY Client, Product
HAVING LAST(Amount) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Client,Product, LAST(Amount) 
FROM Table
WHERE product IN (SELECT product
                FROM table)   and LAST>0
GROUP BY Client, Product
```